# Javascript posponing dispatch of click event, eventListener

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I am currently developing some automation tool. Now I am facing issue, which I do not know, how to handle. I am listening on click event and gathering information about event.target, like tagName, all atributes, htmlPath from the root etc. My problem is that it works well, unless I click on some button/link which is causing navigation, in that case my algorithm do not make it to gather all information and as a result nothing is saved.

What I can do about this? Is there way to postpone actual click, if I am listening on click event ? Any other ideas ?

Comment: If you don't want the event to do what it supposed to do, [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). For examle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhu5qLb1/1/).

Comment: I want them to do what they suppose to do, I just want them to do it after I save all information. So basically if I look at that js.fiddle. I want to do something like this:    `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    anotherFunction which needs to be done;
    performAactual click 
});`

@fuyushimoya

Comment: Then first make sure `anotherFunction` accepts callback which it'll call when it completes its work, then pass a function with something code like `window.location.href = the_href;` where `the_href` is the `href` of the clicked anchor, then it can navigate you to the target page.